# Detect column where the item is rendered in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` that uses a `GridLayoutManager` to render my dataset.

The `spanCount` for the layout manager is 2, but I am setting a `SpanSizeLookup` so I can display some items as rows (spanSize=2) and others that only occupy half width (spanSize=1).

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 2);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
   @Override
   public int getSpanSize(int position) {
       return getSpanSizeByPosition(position);
   }
});
```

Now I need to detect (in the adapter `onBindViewHolder()` method if possible) if the item will be rendered on the left or right side, in case it is a "half-width" item.

It would be trivial if all the items were "half-width" items. A simple validation `boolean buttonIsOnTheLeft = position % 2 == 0;` would be enough. But this doesn't work if not all items are "half-width".

I suspect I will need to work with the layout manager to find that information, but not sure how...

So, is someone seeing how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the `onBindViewHolder()` method I just need to call this method that I implemented:

```
private boolean isButtonIsOnTheLeft(int position, NodeStructureTreeViewAdapter adapter) {
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = adapter.getLayoutManager();
        int spanIndex = layoutManager.getSpanSizeLookup().getSpanIndex(position, layoutManager.getSpanCount());
        return spanIndex == 0;
}
```

Of course, I implemented the method `getLayoutManager()` in my adapter the retrieves it from the instance of the recyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [`GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) of each `ViewHolder`, then You will get access to `getSpanIndex` and `getSpanSize`.

However those values are set after view is laid out which happens later (and more often) than `onBindViewHolder()`. Callback for this event is `onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)` method:

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    // ... 

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        if(holder.itemView.getLayoutParams() instanceof GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams){
            GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            holder.title.setText("In column "+lp.getSpanIndex()+", size "+lp.getSpanSize());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know about that onViewAttachedToWindowd(). However, I would need to notify the adapter that the item changed, so the information is updated right? It is no possible in the `onBindViewHolder()` method? Or somewhere before the view is rendered?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `getSpanIndex()`, this was really helpful. I found that you can use this in an ItemDecorator where you get passed `itemView` directly to avoid having to use `onViewAttachedToWindow`.